# Write Spark Dataset to Excel File along with partitioning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, spark-excel

I have a Dataset similar to the below structure:

```
col_A      col_B        date
  1          5       2021-04-14
  2          7       2021-04-14
  3          5       2021-04-14
  4          9       2021-04-14
```

I am trying to use the below code in Spark Java to write the dataaset to a file in HDFS.

```
Dataset<Row> outputDataset; // This is a valid dataset and works flawlessly when written to csv
/*
   some code which sets the outputDataset
*/
outputDataset
    .repartition(1)
    .write()
    .partitionBy("date")
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("/saveLoc/sales");
```

**Normal Working Case:**

When I pass use `.format("csv")`, the above code creates a folder with the name `date=2021-04-14` in the path `/saveLoc/sales` that is passed in `.save()` which is exactly as expected. The full path of the end file is `/saveLoc/sales/date=2021-04-14/someFileName.csv`. Also, the column `date` is removed from the file since it was partitioned on.

**What I need to do:**

However, when I use `.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")`, it just creates a plain file called `sales` in the folder `saveLoc` and doesn't remove the partitioned(date) column from the end file. Does that mean it isn't partitioning on the column "date"? Full path of the file created is `/saveLoc/sales`. Please note that it overrides the *folder* "sales" with a *file* sales.

Excel plugin used is descibed here: https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

How can I make it parition when writing in excel? In other words, how can I make it behave exactly as it did in case of csv?

Versions used:

```
spark-excel: com.crealytics.spark-excel_2.11
scala: org.apache.spark.spark-core_2.11
```

Thanks.